# odd behaviour phpunit with laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

This is a sample code that should tell me if my action redirects to a specific URI.

```
public function testBasicExample()
{

    $response = $this->action('GET', 'UserController@action');

    $this->assertRedirectedTo('/');

}
```

I am using Laravel 4 with built in config.xml. Shouldn't there be only one assertion? One assertion checks for the redirect what's the other one for? Also, it's not standard phpunit assertion, it comes with Laravel. Below is my console output:

```
Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 6.25Mb

←[30;42m←[2KOK (1 test, 2 assertions)
```

Also i have intentionally put the redirect there so i can confirm that the redirect is right.

Comment: Laravel comes with TestExample class which is probably run together with your test, so check that.

Comment: well, i am already using the same ExampleTest that ships with Laravel 4 and there is only one method that i mentioned above.